# SSL Pinning in Android with network-security-config

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, public-key-pinning

I have this code in my app

In `res>xml>network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">MY_DOMAIN.com</domain>
        <pin-set>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">MY_PIN</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I found `MY_PIN` inserting `MY_DOMAIN.com` here: https://report-uri.com/home/pkp_hash

In `manifest>AndoridManifest.xml`

```
...
 <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

I load `MY_DOMAIN` in a WebView

But it's like if `res>xml>network_security_config.xml` is never opened and checked: if i change `MY_PIN` it still working and loading the page of `MY_DOMAIN`

Comment: What do you mean by "loading the page"? Do you mean `WebView`? If so, what version of Android are you running on, as `WebView` did not honor network security configuration in the beginning.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm developing on Android 8 (26 API, Oreo) and I use ```android.webkit.WebView``` in my app. In the onCreate i simply do:
```webView.loadUrl(MY_DOMAIN.com);```
I can not see my error, can you? Thanks

Comment: [Solved in my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56002828/10867716). Hope this helps.