# Android WebView and network-security-configuration

Tags: android, android-webview, android-network-security-config

I'm developing on Android 8 (26 API, Oreo) and I use `android.webkit.WebView` in my app.

I would implement "secure network connection" when I load pages with my `WebView` (in other words I would avoid man-in-the-middle problems and self-signed certificates)

To do this I used network security configuration (on Android from version 7.0 N, 24 API)

So:

In `res>xml>network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">MY_DOMAIN.com</domain>
        <pin-set>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">MY_PIN</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I found `MY_PIN` inserting `MY_DOMAIN.com` here: https://report-uri.com/home/pkp_hash

In `manifest>AndoridManifest.xml`

```
...
 <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
...
 </application>
```

In the onCreate of my app I simply do:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(..)..
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished()..
    ...});
webView.loadUrl(MY_DOMAIN.com);
```

According to Android docs I'm doing it right but I have a problem: it's like `network_security_config.xml` is never checked because I can set every "random" and "wrong" value for the pin and it works normally (URL `MY_DOMAIN.com` is loaded normally without blocking behavior).

So that means that if some man-in-the-middle return back one different pin of those I've written in `res>xml>network_security_config.xml` the application continue running well and with no secure behavior. 
It also does not execute one of the overridden error method of `WebViewClient`.

Please help I can not understand my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SOLVED]

In AndoridManifest.xml I declared

```
 <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
 ...
 </application>
```

Editor warned about a problem related to the SDK version but I didn't see it.
[This is the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAp80.png).

[SOLUTION]

Add this `tools:targetApi="n"` to the Manifest like the following:

```
<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...
    tools:targetApi="n">
```

[EDIT]

SSL error is handled in `public void onReceivedSslError(...)`  of `WebViewClient` (See the following code)

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, 
                final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                     //HANDLE HERE THE ERROR!!!
                ...
            }
        ...
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, for me this only works in a real device， not work on  emulators

Comment: I'm having issues with WebChromeClient. How would you track onReceivedSslError on WebChromeClient ?

Comment: @IlkerBaltaci I think you have to create the WebView and set on it both the WebViewClient and the WebChromeClient. 
In other words, it is not correct to say that "you receive the error on the WebChromeClient". You receive the error on the WebView. And to handle it you have to set the WebViewClient and do the explained.