# Android 11 : usesCleartextTraffic doesn't work, but run on android 9

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I hope you can help me. I have a problem with request HTTP

I have tried using:

- clear text traffic

  **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**
- network security config

  **android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"**

network_security_config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
 <domain includeSubdomains="true"><my IP request></domain>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

the result remains the same, response :
[run in android 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5R1S.png)

but, the code can run on android 9

can anyone help me to solve it, thank you

Comment: Is this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001973/android-webview-and-network-security-configuration

Comment: not yet, it still shows blank white space, and then showing err_cleartext_not_permitted

Comment: Have you tried running `flutter clean` after modifying the AndroidManifest?

Comment: I've tried it, but doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try with editing AndroidManifest.xml and app level build.gradle file with below

1. AndroidManifest.xml file put
   `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />`
   under `<application>` tag
2. In build.gradle file put useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' on below compileSdkVersion
   under android{}

Comment: I've tried it, but it still doesn't work